# Connecting Non Mesh Consul Servers to a Consul Mesh in Another Data Centre

Tags: consul, hashicorp

We are currently running Consul as a Service Registry internally on an OpenShift cluster, we about to run a Consul Service Mesh on GCP GKE and need to be able to synchronise the registries between internal and GCP to provide a single view, through Consul 'data centres'.
The challenge we have is we can’t run a mesh internally due to corporate constraints on the Openshift Cluster.
My question is, can we connect our internal Consul servers to our GCP Consul Mesh, through the GCP Mesh Gateway without enabling Consul Connect internally?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Consul's [sync catalog](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/service-sync) feature. You can use this to synchronize the Kubernetes service registry on OpenShift with the registry in the remote cluster.

> can we connect our internal Consul servers to our GCP Consul Mesh, through the GCP Mesh Gateway without enabling Consul Connect internally?

You cannot use mesh gateways to enable connectivity between clusters without enabling Connect in both environments.

If your goal is to make the GCP cluster's Consul API available to the on-premises OpenShift cluster, you can more easily achieve this by exposing the API through a Kubernetes load balancer or ingress resource.

Comment: Thanks, we've managed to get the gateways running on OpenShift so will use that

Comment: Glad to hear you decided to use Connect. Do you mind if I ask why you downvoted this answer if it is still valid for non-Connect deployments?

Comment: Sorry, that was by accident